# Redirecting to a page from dropdown select and button click

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

*I am New to angular , and is there anything like we should select a option from dropdown and then click a button to redirect into the particular selected option*

```
            <mat-label  >Login As</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
               <mat-option value="option">Agriculture Farmer</mat-option>
               <mat-option value="option">Agriculture Merchant</mat-option>
               <mat-option value="option">Aquaculture Farmer</mat-option>
               <mat-option value="option">Aquaculture Merchant</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
         </mat-form-field>
         <button mat-raised-button color="warn" style="width:70%">Login</button>

*when click on login, should go to a specific path*
```

Comment: This is very generic, please share some code and where you are stuck.

Comment: could you please help me with that !

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd use a component like [mat-menu](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) where'd you'd specify the dropdown options, and then for the `<button>` elements inside the menu you'd add a `routerLink` (if navigating to a route within your app) or an `href` if referencing a url.

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item href="https://google.com">Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/foo">Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```